# How to merge list elements?

Tags: python

Is there a way on python to merge all list elements into one string similar to this pseudo code?

```
thislist = ["2", "3", "5"]
m = thislist.merge_or_something()
print(m)
```

And it should return the following:

```
"235"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: you can use the `join`  like `"".join(thislist)`

Comment: If you want to all in one index , You can use reduce like : `m = [reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, thislist)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `join` with a string.

`''.join(myList)`

`join` is a method for the string that uses the string as a separator for printing an iterator like a list.

for example, using `,` as separator help you to create csv.;

```
myList = [1,2,3]
','.join(myList)
#output 
1,2,3
```